Я не вызывал принт в питоне, но он просто сам по себе выводит значение импортированных переменных
from TRY_PARSER import fulltext_btc, fulltext_dollar, fulltext_eth

вот это весь код мой в одну строчку, я импортировал переменные из TRY_PARSER, и теперь когда я запускаю этот код длинною в одну строчку, получаю данные этих переменных, хотя даже не вызывал print().

Вангую, что в коде TRY_PARSER есть print-ы, не защищённые конструкцией if __name__ == '__main__': и не расположенные внутри функций. Прямо вот на верхнем уровне. Они, естественно, будут выполнены при импорте. Ну, или там есть вызовы функций, на этом верхнем уровне, в которых уже есть print-ы.
